# How to disregard the indentation for this dottedline

Tags: indentation

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dottedlinefillheight
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.3in}

\def\fillwithdottedlines{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \dottedlinefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
          \dotfill}%
  \cleaders \copy0 \vfill \hbox{}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]
    \item test
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
        \end{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test
                \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This `\fillwithdottedlines` was copied from another post on this forum.

How can I disregard the indentation, so that the line is always textwidth?

I think it something to do with `\@totalleftmargin` and I tried to use `\leftmargin` instead, but the result does not seem good.

Result of using `\leftmargin` is given below:

[image]

1 - they are not aligned.
2 - there are still some indentation.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly adding the space, just remove (or as here comment it out)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dottedlinefillheight
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.3in}

\def\fillwithdottedlines{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{%\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \dottedlinefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
          \dotfill}%
  \cleaders \copy0 \vfill \hbox{}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]
    \item test
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
        \end{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test
                \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: easier than thought. I was overthinking of something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `enumitem` package instead of `enumerate`, and use the `wide` option for 2nd and 3rd level enumerations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dottedlinefillheight
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{.3in}

\def\fillwithdottedlines{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \dottedlinefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
          \dotfill}%
  \cleaders \copy0 \vfill \hbox{}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]
    \item test
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
        \end{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test
                \begin{enumerate}[(i),wide = 0pt]
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the dotted line full text width, use this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[Q1., wide = 0pt]
    \item test
        \begin{enumerate}[(a), wide]
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
            \item test test
            \fillwithdottedlines
        \end{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item test
                \begin{enumerate}[(i),wide, leftmargin =\dimexpr-\leftmargini + \labelsep-\fontdimen2\font]
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                    \fillwithdottedlines
                    \item test
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: your lines aren't \textwidth though, as asked in the question, they are still indented by the list indent, as seen by the Q2 being to the left.

Comment: @David Carlisle: True. I understood the lines had to start at the left margin of the list.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I've added a variant, always based on enumitem, that makes dotted lines full width.